# How can I get a manipulated parameter to show up with text next to it?

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

I'm trying to make a dynamic demonstration involving the $\epsilon-\delta$ proof of the limit, $$\lim_{x\to c}(2x-1)=2c-1$$
with the following code. `d` and `e` correspond to $\delta$ and $\epsilon$.

```
d[e_]=e/2;
Manipulate[
    Row[{d[e], Plot[2x-1, {x,-1,4}]}],
    {c,0,3},
    {e,0,5},
    SaveDefinitions->True]
```

I've omitted the part of the code that contains `c` (it's a bunch of lines added via `Epilog`).

I would like to make the label to the left, currently the value of `d` given a fixed `e`, like `d=(value of d)`, which I've tried using `"d=" d[e]`. However, this displays the value I want followed by the text `d=`. I can't seem to find anything that addresses this option in the documentation.

**Edit:** I'm now considering including the current values of `c` and `e` in a column to the right of the plot. I've changed the code as follows:

```
d[e_]=e/2;
Manipulate[
    Row[
        {Plot[2x-1, {x,-1,4}],
         Column[{{"e=",e}, {"d=",e/2}, {"c=",c}}]}
     ],
        {c,0,3},
        {e,0,5},
    SaveDefinitions->True]
```

but this gives me awkward labels that look like `{e=,0}` when `e` is $0$, for example.

Comment: Try `"d=" <> ToString[d[e]]` where you now have `d[e]`.

Comment: Just add a comma between `"d = "` and `d[e]`, i.e. `Row[{"d = ", d[e], Plot[2 x - 1, {x, -1, 4}]}]`?

Comment: Thanks @kguler for the very simple fix :)

Comment: Did you consider using the `Appearance` option:  `{e,0,5,Appearance->"Labeled"}` ?  The label appears at the end of the slider but is a bit less visible than the solution below.  (This, of course, doesn't help with displaying `d`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d[e_] = e/2;

Manipulate[Row[{"d = ", d[e], Plot[2 x - 1, {x, -1, 4}, ImageSize -> 300]}, Spacer[5]], 
 {e, 0, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Perhaps a better alternative is to use `Labeled` and to wrap the label with `Pane` to avoid jittering of the plot as the size of the label changes:

```
Manipulate[Labeled[Plot[2 x - 1, {x, -1, 4}], 
  Pane[Row@{"d = ", d[e]}, ImageSize -> 100], Left], 
 {e, 0, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update:**

> ... *including the current values of `c` and `e` in a column to the right of the plot.*

```
Manipulate[Labeled[Plot[2 x - 1, {x, -1, 4}], 
  Pane[Column[Row /@ {{"e = ", e}, {"d = ", e/2}, {"c = ", c}}], 
   ImageSize -> {100, Automatic}], Right], {c, 0, 3}, {e, 0, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, instead of `Column[Row /@ {{"e = ", e}, {"d = ", e/2}, {"c = ", c}}]` use

```
Grid[{{"e = ", e}, {"d = ", e/2}, {"c = ", c}}]
```

Comment: Yes! I've been looking for way to stop the constant shifting. Do you have any suggestions regarding displaying the column of parameters?

Comment: @user170231, I updated with a suggestion to display a column of parameters on the right.

Comment: Ah I see, I have to nest `Row` within `Column`. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @user170231, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept. You could also use `Grid` instead of  `Column/Row` combination: `Grid[{{"e = ", e}, {"d = ", e/2}, {"c = ", c}}]` is perhaps more straightforward than `Column[Row/@{...}]`.

Comment: `Grid` introduces some alignment issues, but that's easily dealt with.